# Converting Date Format in a Dataframe from a CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I need to convert the date format of my csv file into the proper pandas format so I could sort it later on. My current format cannot be interacted reasonably in pandas so I had to convert it.

This is what my csv file looks like:

```
ARTIST,ALBUM,TRACK,DATE
ARTIST1,ALBUM1,TRACK1,23 Nov 2019 02:08
ARTIST1,ALBUM1,TRACK1,23 Nov 2019 02:11
ARTIST1,ALBUM1,TRACK1,23 Nov 2019 02:15
```

So far I've successfully converted it into pandas format by doing this:

```
df= pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv", delimiter=',')
convertdate= pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
print convertdate

####

#Original date format: 23 Nov 2019 02:08
#Output and desired date format: 2019-11-23 02:08:00
```

However, that only changes the values in the entire "DATE" column. Printing the dataframe of the csv file still outputs the original, non-converted date format. I need to append the converted format into the source csv file.

My desired output would then be

```
ARTIST,ALBUM,TRACK,DATE
ARTIST1,ALBUM1,TRACK1,2019-11-23 02:08:00
ARTIST1,ALBUM1,TRACK1,2019-11-23 02:11:00
ARTIST1,ALBUM1,TRACK1,2019-11-23 02:15:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options to the [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method. 
Make sure to read the data in in the format you want instead of fixing it later.

```
df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv"', parse_dates=['DATE'])
```

Just pass in to the parse_dates argument the column names you want transformed.

There were 2 problems in the original code.
It wasn't a part of the original dataframe because you didn't save it back to the column once you transformed it.

so instead of:

```
convertdate= pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
```

use:

```
df["DATE"]= pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
```

and for goodness sake [stop using python 2](https://pythonclock.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', parse_dates=['DATE'], date_parser=dateparse)
```